# MLFlow in container is not mapped to host port

Tags: docker, mlflow

I am learning about MLFlow and Docker Containers.
I created an ubuntu container and mapped port 5001 of the host to 5000 of the container.

```
docker run -it -p 5001:5000 -v D:\Docker\mlflow:/home --name mlflow ubuntu:18.04 bash
```

Inside the container, I installed the mlflow using pip

```
pip install mlflow
```

[image]

When I run the mlflow UI it's running but I can't access it from my host PC (localhost:5001) is not working.

Did I do any mistakes anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are starting the server on `127.0.0.1` and the port mapping was not pointing to this interface (socket hang up). Starting it on all interfaces `0.0.0.0` works.

You should just run this command in the container.

```
mlflow ui -h 0.0.0.0
```